# Error in GET DATA SQL query function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, spss

OK, I'm using GET DATA to pull data using an ODBC connection. I'm going to use production facility to repeatedly automate the data pull, and I'd like to do it YTD.

Currently, including this is the part of the SQL subcommand I manipulate to change the date range:

```
between '09/03/2014 12:00:00 AM' and '09/02/2015 11:59:59 PM'
```

So far, I've gotten this to work the same:

```
between '09/03/2015 12:00:00 AM' and CURDATE() + ' 11:59:59 PM'
```

However, I'm going to set up to run so I need it to be YTD ending on the previous to the day it runs. So, that would look like this:

```
between {fn CONVERT( { fn DATE_SUB({ fn CURDATE()}, INTERVAL 365 DAY) }, SQL_CHAR ) } + ' 12:00:00 AM' and {fn CONVERT( { fn DATE_SUB({ fn CURDATE()}, INTERVAL 1 DAY) }, SQL_CHAR ) } + ' 11:59:59 PM'
```

The error I'm getting says this:

> SQLExecDirect failed :[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '365'.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to format 365 differently. If I just have a date typed in for the beginning of the date range, I get the same error for the '1' on the end.

EDIT: Update, so the question has been posed if this is MySQL or SQL Server (my apologies, I have little to know experience and didn't know the difference initially). However, it seems to be both in a couple ways.

As you can see in the error I posted above, it references Microsoft sql server. Also, the documentation from SPSS (the program I'm working in) references [this MS site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711813(VS.85).aspx) for functions to use, but those seem to be mysql.

Also, when I use this version of the script (using sql server functions), I get an error saying GetDate isn't a recognized function. If I switch that to CURDATE(), then DATADD() is the problem.

```
{fn CONVERT( { fn DATEADD(day,-1,{ fn GETDATE() }) }, SQL_CHAR ) }  + ' 12:00:00 AM' and {fn CONVERT( { fn DATEADD(year,-01,{ fn GETDATE() }) }, SQL_CHAR ) }  + ' 11:59:59 PM'
```

If I trim out the curly brackets and such, and stick with SQL server functions, this gives me an error for incorrect syntax near ','

```
CONVERT(DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()), SQL_CHAR)  + ' 12:00:00 AM' and CONVERT(DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), SQL_CHAR)  + ' 11:59:59 PM'
```

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server?  looks like sql-server...please edit post

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying a mashup between mysql and MS SQL Server. Basically, DATE_SUB is a MYSQL function, yet you seem to be using it against an MS SQL Server.

What you should be using if i understand your work environment is http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp
with a negative value.

PS - why use 365 DAY when you can use 1 YEAR (and this way leap years won't become a problem in the long run).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then again, if CURDATE() works, you're probably connecting to MYSQL. Can you please tell us what kind of database you're using? your post points to both MYSQL and MSSQL. Thanks!

Comment: it seems to be SQL server.

Comment: Let's try to simplify as much as possible and see if it works.. Instead of between x and y try > date_sub( now(), interval 1 YEAR) - the results should be similar. Now() also includes the time so you shouldn't have to use convert anymore